# Pass data for Readonly Data type when execute a SP in sql

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-update, ssms, readonly

I need to execute a SP in Sql Server. I excute the SP using external Script as follows.

```
Declare @partid int
Declare @Quantity float
Declare @unitCost float

Exec PRAMA.ins_parts @partid ,5,@Quantity ,@unitCost,'Adjusting balance' ,null
```

In the PRAMA.ins_parts SP,

```
Create PROCEDURE [ins_parts]
      @part_id as int
    , @act as int
    , @qty as float
    , @cost as float
    , @comment as nvarchar(500)
    , @codes product_codes READONLY
    
AS
BEGIN
END
```

Then when I execute the above query for and pass the data to SP it displays an error message
"Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with Codes"

Is there any way to fix this issue? Can any one suggest me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for above question.

First you have to declare the table type parameter in your query and then insert data to it.
In my "product_codes" table it has id (int) and code (varchar)columns.

```
 Declare @product_codes Parts_Product_Codes
    Declare @partid int
    Declare @Quantity float
    Declare @unitCost float

Insert into @product_codes Values(null,null)

    Exec PRAMA.ins_parts @partid ,5,@Quantity ,@unitCost,'Adjusting balance' ,@product_codes
```